# Selection of parameters for building a depth map using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, depth, stereoscopy

There is a calibrated stereopair with which I build a depth map using the StereoSGBM algorithm from the openCV library. The algorithm provides the ability to configure via the built-in parameters: setBlockSize, setDisp12MaxDiff, setMinDisparity, setNumDisparities, setSpeckleRange, setSpeckleWindowSize, setMode, etc. When using the standard example from opencv, the depth map is constructed excellent, but if you use your images then the depth map is built incorrectly.

Hence the question - how correctly to choose the values ​​of the above parameters to build a depth map? Are there any instructions for selecting parameters? Are there any programs for automatically selecting these parameters?